# How to Redirect to error pages without changing the url

Tags: .htaccess

I have an error folder, which contains `404.php` `403.php` `500.php`
I want to redirect user to the error page of any (if 404; redirect to `404.php`, if 403; redirect to `403.php`, if 500; redirect to `500.php`) without changing the URL.

Here is my code in my `htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ /error/404.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ /error/403.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ /error/500.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.php
```

Comment: This changes the URL to the `ErrorDocument` URL